# Network latency problems - Server stress testing

Tags: networking, httprequest, delay, latency, stress-testing

I am doing a server stress testing using Apache Benchmark Tool and Apache jMeter. With 30 and more concurrent requests, network starts to lag (every 100-200 requests).

Although there are no CPU load on server and have plenty of free memory.

For example, 200 requests perform with 50ms latency and then ~10 requests performs with latency over 3000 ms, and it keeps going like this.

Please note, server **DOES NOT** run Apache nor MySQL, therefore Apache is not the problem. Node.JS was used for stress testing and it seem to handle load perfectly well. I tried doing same experiment with apache and static content and got same result with delays.

Server configuration:

```
- Leaseweb
- Intel Xeon X3440
- 8GB DDR3
- 1 x 100Mbps Full-Duplex
```

What could be a problem and how can i monitor weak spots? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Software also seem's not to matter.
As it doesn't matter what software serve runs.

Server will be running Node.JS only but we tested with apache too and got same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confident that seeing the same results with a different target server means that the target server is not the problem. If you are correct, then the two remaining possibilities are the load generator and the network. Try using two load generators (at the same network location). If you get the exact same results, then the load generators are likely not to blame. If the results change, then the bottleneck is on the load generator.